All Possible Combinations (cartesian product) Script/Functions with no duplicate values
At a school, we are trying to determine if based on when we are able to offer all of our classes (master schedule) if based on each student's course requests can a schedule be built where they receive all 8 courses with no duplicates.
enter image description here
SITUATIONAL DOCUMENT: Shows input and desired result: (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1a7hnOlxe774xo_Rscud6jVldeKzz3ltautvB3wU03hk/edit?usp=sharing)
I need to do be able to do this for over 1000 students. Finding ALL possible solutions for some students results in 10,000s of possibilities IF you require that every column be unique. This is the step I can't figure out how to do efficiently.
I received results by using this formula found on Stack Overflow:
LINK TO ANSWER
=index(split(flatten(flatten(flatten(flatten(flatten(flatten(flatten(flatten(
transpose(filter(D4:D11,D4:D11<>"")))&"|"&transpose(filter(E4:E11,E4:E11<>"")))&"|"&transpose(filter(F4:F11,F4:F11<>"")))&"|"&
transpose(filter(G4:G11,G4:G11<>"")))&"|"&transpose(filter(H4:H11,H4:H11<>"")))&"|"&
transpose(filter(I4:I11,I4:I11<>"")))&"|"&transpose(filter(J4:J11,J4:J11<>"")))&"|"&
transpose(filter(K4:K11,K4:K11<>""))),"|"))
I then used a "=countunique()" function to see how many unique values were in each row. I then filtered the entire range of possibilities (over 75,000 rows for some) to display only those that the function returned "8"... meaning no class was duplicated during the day.
The problem is, this took roughly 15secs per student after scripting to use the function above. There MUST be a faster / more efficient method. I don't need ALL of the cartesian possibilities shown. I just need the ones that are unique in every column. Please help!
